# GMAJ error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.StringBuffer cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: sequence-alignment, visualization, software-installation, maf

I have installed [GMAJ](http://globin.bx.psu.edu/dist/gmaj/gmaj_install.html) using:

```
wget http://globin.bx.psu.edu/dist/gmaj/gmaj.zip  -O output/software/gmaj.zip
unzip -u output/software/gmaj.zip -d output/software/gmaj/
rm output/software/gmaj.zip
```

I ran [lastz](http://www.bx.psu.edu/miller_lab/dist/README.lastz-1.02.00/README.lastz-1.02.00a.html) on two chromosomes from two different assemblies of *C. elegans*:

`lastz c_elegans.PRJNA13758.WS263.genomicI.fa I.fa --format=maf > MAF.maf`

and got a MAF file.

Then, I tried to visualise the file using:

`java -jar output/software/gmaj/gmaj.jar MAF.maf`

but I got the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.StringBuffer cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    at edu.psu.bx.gmaj.MajGui.setDefaults(MajGui.java:272)
    at edu.psu.bx.gmaj.Maj.<init>(Maj.java:53)
    at edu.psu.bx.gmaj.MajMain.main(MajMain.java:86)
```

Can someone help me resolve this error or suggest an alternative way to visualise my alignment?

I work on Mac OS X.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

It's a programming error that should look like this:

```
StringBuffer sb = (...)
(...)
String s = (String)sb;
```

while it should be

```
StringBuffer sb = (...)
(...)
String s = sb.toString();
```

( see also https://www.biostars.org/p/177992/ ) . You cannot do anything about it but asking the authors of the software.

Comment: Sent an email to Cathy Riemer asking for help.